# From GCS_WGS_1984 to UTM WGS 84 zone 33N

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

I was doing my project and I had to transform a shapefile from Bessel to gcs_wgs_1984, that went fine. Now I have to put it again to projected coordinate system.

Please could someone help me transform it from WGS_1984 to UTM wgs_84 zone 33N?

Comment: These two coordinate systems use the same datum so transformation is not required. Simply use the Project tool to project the GCS data to a PCS.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you should be able to go to **Toolbox->Data Management->Projections and Transformations->Feature->Project**.

There, simply select your dataset and then click the button for **output coordinate system**, where you can browse to **Projected Cordinate Systems->UTM->WGS 1984->Northern Hemisphere->WGS 1984 UTM Zone 33N.prj** and press **Open**, **Apply** then **OK**.

If you press **OK** again then it should do it. Normally to do a transformation like this, you would have to specify a specific transformation (in the last box), but Arc does not seem to have any valid transformations in this case (for me at least), so I would say that you should be careful to check that it has worked properly (by checking that it lines up properly with some other data).

How is that?